# python program ask user to input n number and tell him the biggest among these numbers when the user type 0 the program should stop

Tags: python

python program ask the user to input n number and tell him the biggest among these numbers when the user type 0 the program should stop and 0 shouldn't be compared to the other numbers   (if he input 0 in number 1 it should input the first number till he inputs a correct number )

```
number = -1
i = 1

while not (number == 0):
    number = float(input(f"Number {i} : "))
    while number == 0 and i == 1:
        number = float(input(f"Number {i} : "))

    if i == 1 or number > max:
        max = number
        position = i

    i += 1

if i == 1:
    print("thank u ...")
else:
    print(f"the greatest number is {max}, his postion is {position}.")
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: when I ran the code the 0 is included in the comparison

Comment: @Tomerikoo I want 0 just to stop the process not to be compared to

Comment: So [edit] your post and include that in the form of a question... Please take the [tour] and read about [ask] before you continue to use the site

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python program prompts user to enter number until they enter 0, then program adds even and odd integers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44124059/6045800)

Comment: Your loop checks if the number is not 0 after you already used it. Instead you need to use a `while True` and inside the loop check if the number is 0 and if it is - `break` the loop

Comment: @Tomerikoo I cannot edit it idw

Answer (score 0):

you can solve your probleme like below. In your example your first while loop should be executed just until it's getting the right number for 'n'.

```
n = 0
while n <=0:
    n = float(input(f"Number of el : "))
position = 1
max = None
i = 1
while i <= n:
    number = float(input(f"Number {i}: "))
    if max is None or number > max:
        max = number
        position = i
    i+=1
print(f"the greatest number is {max}, his postion is {position}.")
```

Comment: But there is no input for the number of elements... Did you read the question? The user inputs numbers until the input 0 stops the process. In that case, why even use the second loop as a `while`? Why not just `for i in range(n)`?